# Transform basis of a space to make a given vector just a number in one dimension, zero in the rest?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products

Given any vector in an n-dimensional space, is there always a linear transformation that can be applied to the basis of that space so that the given vector coincides with exactly one of the transformed basis of that space?

In other words, given any vector in an n-dimensional space, is it possible to apply a linear transformation to the basis of that space so that the given vector will have at least `n - 1` zeros in it?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Any nonzero vector is a part of some basis. In such a basis all but one if its coordinates are all $0$, and that one is $1$. There is always a linear transformation that turns any given basis into another given basis.